# Entity Framework extra properties are not populated by DbContext.Database.SqlQuery

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When I add extra properties to a EF auto-generated class by using an extra partial class, these properties are not populated or filled when running queries against the database.

Example:

Auto-Generated class Person:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My own partial class

```
public partial class Person
{
    public string DisplayName{ get; set; }
}
```

When I make the following query:

```
"SELECT *, (FirstName + LastName) AS DisplayName FROM [Person]"
```

and use

```
DbContext.Database.SqlQuery(typePerson, SQL, null)
```

the Id, FirstName and LastName are populated but not the DisplayName.

However when I create a whole new class called MyPerson

```
public partial class MyPerson
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName{ get; set; }
}
```

And run the same query with the type of MyPerson the DisplayName is populated as well.

Can anyone explain this or tell me how I can fix this problem so I can use Partials instead of having to create new classes/types.

Download an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dayrv0jzuoju9q3/StackOverflow_EF_ExtraProperties.zip?dl=0

**UPDATE 2015-12-28:**
While reading through other stackoverflow and Codeproject forums I found another ways to get it to work:

1) Using Typebuilder (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206416/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-SqlQuery) but due to all sort of project dependencies I had problems finding already created types and not blowing up the memory;

2) Best option so far: using inheritance.

When I create another class with just this lines:

```
class Person_Reflect : Person { }
```

I can use the following code (it will ignore the mapping in the EDMX file and use reflection:

```
List<EF.Person> listPerson = dbEntities.Database.SqlQuery<EF.Person_Reflect>(sql, new object[] { }).ToList<EF.Person>();
```

Comment: Are you sure the 2nd partial class of `Person` is in the right namespace?

Comment: And no exception since you have changed the model?

Comment: Do you see DisplayName as a property without value?

Comment: Thx for all your comments! Yes in the same namespace. "No exception"? Can you elaborate on your comment? Yes I see the Displayname as a property with value NULL.

Comment: I have never tried Model-first with EF. But for this particular problem, I would make: 
`public partial class Person
{
    public string DisplayName{ get { return FirstName + LastName; }  }
}`

Comment: To solve this particular problem you're right DroidBot but it's more a conceptual problem. My users can define on runtime their own formats for addresses/person names/etc. These formates are stored in the DB as well and are infused in the SQL queries to return the correct format. I can do this also with regular expressions or evals. But it bugs me that a partial enriched class won't work and a basically the same class coded next to the EF class will work.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for . Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Best option so far without having to code much and or to do much code review when Database changes occur is to use inheritance.

When I create another class with just this line:

```
class Person_Reflect : Person { }
```

I can use the following code (it will ignore the mapping in the EDMX file and use reflection):

```
List<EF.Person> listPerson = dbEntities.Database.SqlQuery<EF.Person_Reflect>(sql, new object[] { }).ToList<EF.Person>();
```

Answer (score 0):

try remove the *

```
@"
 SELECT 
     Id 
    ,FirstName 
    ,LastName 
    ,(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) AS DisplayName 
 FROM [Person]"
```

Alternatively you could do this is code... and then you would not need to include it in your raw sql

```
public string DisplayName { get { return FirstName+ " " +LastName ; } }
```

Comment: Leaving out the * doesn't work, it even makes it worse; if I forget one column the application ends with the exception:
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Application.Person'. A member of the type, 'COLUMNNAME', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
You are absolutely right, your coding solution solves this example but I have a dynamic query that can be enriched on runtime to create a multitude of end user choices of how to display/format results. So I only have a view options: using evals or creating dynamic queries.

Comment: it should work... the column must be the same CASE and data type. I have done something simular myself so i know it works.. please double check case and types

Comment: Dear Seabizkit. I have uploaded a test example in which I can't seem to get it to work what you have accomplished. The link to the full example is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dayrv0jzuoju9q3/StackOverflow_EF_ExtraProperties.zip?dl=0

Comment: FFS why was this down voted. OMG really are people so.... ish @LiQuick.net ill double check myself later.... when im back at work.

Comment: Sorry for the downvoting not my doing.